# Deducting numbers based on value in a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a `C column` with several rows containing numbers. I have another `E Column` with rankings.

I would like a formula that will automatically change the number in a 3rd `column G` based on the ranking in `E column`

So,

- If the ranking is 2 in `E` the number in `G` is number in `column C`
  minus 1
- If the ranking is 1 the number in `E` the number in `G` is
  number in `column C` minus 2
- Any other ranking the number remains the
  same.

**Example -**

- C       E       G
- 19      2      18
- 12      1      10
- 15      3      15

Answer (score 0):

Put below `formula` in `G column` -

```
=IF(E1=1,C1-2,IF(E1=2,C1-1,C1))
```

Above formula is for row 1. Adjust row value according to your need.

**Explanation** -

1. Check if `E column` contains 1, then subtract 2 from `C column`
2. Else, check if `E column` contains 2, then subtract 1 from `C
   column`
3. Else, `G column` is same as `C column`